# restrict users with sessions

Tags: php

I am looking to add pages on my site that only people with a certan rank will be able to see while others will be kicked to a different page. What would be a simple way of doing this?

This is what I have right now.

```
  <?php  session_start(); 
  $rank=$_SESSION['rank'];
  $loggedinusername=$_SESSION['loggedinusername'];
  $loggedinuseremail=$_SESSION['loggedinuseremail'];
  ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**For single allowed rank**

```
if ($rank != 'allowed_rank') {

    header('Location: some_other_page.php');
    exit;
}
```

**For multiplpe allowed ranks**

```
if (!in_array($rank, array('allowed_rank1', 'allowed_rank2'))) {

    header('Location: some_other_page.php');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  session_start();
  if ($_SESSION['rank'] > 1) // or whatever your minimum rank is
  {
     header('Location: highrankpage.php');
  }
  else 
  {
     header('Location: lowrankpage.php');
  }

  exit();

?>
```

You'll want to include this code on every page that you want to protect.

Comment: By adding that it sends me to a blank page

Comment: ok lets try this again, can not get my fingers and brain to work tonight. I added what you suggested. The page that it sends me to is correct but its blank. if take it off the page works as it should.  <br/> <code><?php  session_start(); 
if ($_SESSION['rank'] > 1) {
$rank=$_SESSION['rank'];
$loggedinusername=$_SESSION['loggedinusername'];
$loggedinuseremail=$_SESSION['loggedinuseremail'];    

}
else{
header('Location: index.php');
}
exit();
?><code>

Comment: You have to create the pages ;)  That was just an example - you can replace 'highrankpage.php' and 'lowrankpage.php' with whatever page you want to redirect them to.  So what you wrote works if you want to redirect to index.php if they don't have a high enough rank.  And you don't want any redirect if they have a high enough rank, then what you did also works - you can remove the redirect to 'highrankpagephp'.